# Problema al subir imagenes con Ajax y PHP

Tags: php, ajax

tengo un input tipo file, estoy tratando de subir imagenes mediante Ajax y PHP.
En Ajax el codigo es el siguiente, estoy enviando como prueba la variable nombre para ser recibida como $_POST['nombre']

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
        $('#insertar-registros').click(function(){
            insertar_registros();
        });
        
    });
    
    function insertar_registros (){
        var datos = new FormData();     
        datos.append('action','fetch_data');
        datos.append('nombre','copito');
        var imagenes = document.getElementById('imagenes');
        var imagen = imagenes.files;        
        for(i=0;i<imagen.length;i++){
            datos.append('imagen'+i,imagen[i]);         
        }
        $.ajax({  
            url:"<?php echo $raiz;?>logica/registrar_mascotas.php",
            method: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType:false,
            data:datos,     
            processData:false, 
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data.html1);
            }
        }); 
    }
```

Y en PHP si hago $_POST['nombre'], la variable se muestra correctamente, pero al probar con las imagenes no sucede absolutamente nada, que podria estar haciendo mal a la hora de recorrer los datos, o existe alguna otra forma de realizar lo que yo estoy haciendo ?

```
<?php
class Usuarios {    
    
    public function registrar(){ 
        $ruta = '../imagenes/';
        foreach ($_FILES as $key) {
            if($key['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK ){
                $NombreOriginal = $key['name'];
                $temporal = $key['tmp_name'];
                $Destino = $ruta.$NombreOriginal;
                move_uploaded_file($temporal, $Destino);
            }
        }
        $HTML = 'Imagen subida correctamente';
    }   
    return $HTML;
}
$usuarios = new Usuarios();
if(isset($_POST["action"])){   
    $html1 = $usuarios->registrar();        
    $data = array(       
        "html1" => $html1,  
    );
    echo json_encode($data);    
}
?>
```

Comment: Intenta modificar tu **contentType** prueba poniendo algo como esto: **contentType: 'multipart/form-data'**